# Можно ли сверстать подобный блок c картой?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, вёрстка

Блок разделен на две части:
1. Верхняя часть (серый цвет), это карта (гугл, яндекс или тп) и она должна быть кликабельна
2. Нижняя часть (желтый цвет), это картинка на котором расположен кликабельный текст (пункты меню, логотип)
Основная проблема в том, как можно сверстать так, чтобы и карта и пункты меню были кликабельны ?

[image: футер]

Comment: <div id='div1'><div id='div2'></div><div id='div3'></div></div> Где div1 - то место на странице где должно быть это чудо position: relative, div2 - то что есть карта, ширина 100% высота 100, а div3 - то что с твоим контентом на который можно тыкать, разворачивать и тд. div3 position:absolute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPD:**
На самом деле для этой задачи достаточного и одного повёрнутого дива в обёртке:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 
.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 580px;
  height: 300px;
  right: -90px;
  top: 110px;
  transform: rotate(-25deg);
  background-color: yellow;
}

.child p {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  float: right;
  margin: 100px 130px 0 0;
}

.child p a {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d15990.24507003764!2d30.35555441672363!3d59.935782142696276!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sru!2sru!4v1515617959614" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <div class="child">
    <p>
    <a href="">ПУНКТ 1</a><br /><br />
    <a href="">ПУНКТ 2</a><br /><br />
    <a href="">ПУНКТ 3</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Например, так:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 
.first {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}
 
.second {
  position: absolute;
  width: 580px;
  height: 300px;
  right: -90px;
  top: 110px;
  transform: rotate(-25deg);
  background-color: yellow;
}

.second p {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  float: right;
  margin: 100px 130px 0 0;
}

.second p a {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first"><iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d15990.24507003764!2d30.35555441672363!3d59.935782142696276!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sru!2sru!4v1515617959614" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <div class="second">
    <p>
    <a href="">ПУНКТ 1</a><br /><br />
    <a href="">ПУНКТ 2</a><br /><br />
    <a href="">ПУНКТ 3</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

То есть создаём два абсолютно спозиционированных дива внутри обёртки и один из них поворачиваем так, как нам надо. Конкретный угол поворота, размеры, отступы и т.д. подгоняйте сами по желанию.